# How to pass Request Headers in Jmeter

Tags: apache, jmeter, header, token, extract

I want to pass the below RefreshTokenCredential in Header part.

After passing this token, I want to get the value of id_token which is showing in textview as shown below.

Please let me know how to pass this token in Jmeter and how to get the id_token?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `Header Manager` to your script. Since you are getting token  as part of HTML, you need to use `Regex Extractor` to get the token

Regex expression `<input type="hidden" name="idToken" value="(.*?)">`

[image]

**Setting Headers**
[image]

**Setting Regex**
[image]

**Regex test**
[image]

Comment: It is working fine now. Great!! Thanks. please check on my another question stackoverflow.com/questions/68116889/… please guide me on that, if you knows it

Answer (score 1):

1. To pass the token add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the request to which you want to add the token to and configure it like:

   [image]
2. To extract the "id_token" value add [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) as a child of that request and configure it like:

   [image]

   you will be able to use extracted value as `${id_token}` where required

Comment: It is working fine now. Great!! Thanks.

please check on my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68116889/how-to-get-the-refreshtoken-from-azure-in-jmeter

please guide me on that, if you knows it