# How to get the RefreshToken from Azure in Jmeter

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, extract, preprocessor

The refreshcredential which is shown below image is coming into Request header part. Currently I am hardcoding this token value. The token is expiring on every 5 mins. After 5 min, the test cases will get fail.

how to extract this dynamic token value and how to add it in Request header part in Jmeter.

Also How to generate this token in Jmeter after 5 min. Please guide me. Its a greatest blocker for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create another thread group. Add your transactions to generate token. Save it to property. Wait for 4 mins.

[image]

[image]

While doing this the two thread groups (token thread group and other http requests) will have to run parallel. Uncheck this option at Test Plan level
[image]

**EDIT**

To extract header follow this thread: [Extract Location from Response Header with JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305507/extract-location-from-response-header-with-jmeter)

Comment: This token is coming from Azure server. How to capture the token that is coming from azure in Jmeter. I want to capture this token while coming from azure in Jmeter then I want to pass this token value to Http request. Pls let me know how to capture this RefreshTokenCredential from azure in Jmeter.

Comment: In your answer you have mentioned "add your transactions to generate token ". But this token is coming from azure and its not storing in any response data. Hence I am not able to capture it. Is there any way to capture this token from azure. Pls help me on this

Comment: If it is issued by Azure then you have less control over it